# Symfony, How can I use Guard with FosUserBundle?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-forms

With Symfony 3.2 I want to use CAS to authenticate users. Currently, I'm using fosuserbundle to authenticate users against MySQL, but I want to switch to Guard.

I read all about guard and I understand that I need to implement some methods, like getCredentials, getUser, onAuthenticationFailure, etc, but is there any parameter that I need to update in the security.yml? How can I have Guard to handle the authentications and fosuserbundle just handle the forms?

Here is my security.yml file

```
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username
firewalls:
    main:
        form_login:
            #provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
```

I have a class that extending AbstractGuardAuthenticator but nothing seems to ge called.

In summary how can I use Guard with fosuserbundle.?

Thank you all in advance.